# Estimate power draw with CPU usage

Tags: cpu, power-consumption

Is there a way to estimate the power consumption with the CPU usage that is shown in the task manager, if I know the TDP?
To be clear, I am talking about the power consumption of the CPU alone, and not the entire system.

Comment: No, at least not easily as you don't know whenever it's linear or not. It would also (kind of) depend on what tools your motherboard has available to supplement the data and might also depend on the type of CPU/CPU itself. Depending on it you might e. g. use [Intel® Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20).

Comment: To add to @Seth's answer, the Task Manager reports the percentage based on the current capacity of the CPU.  If the CPU is running hot, the CPU will throttle itself down to a slower speed, so 100% usage "right now" may only be 70-80%* of the actual full CPU speed.  Also, as electronics heat up, they tend to draw more power, causing them to heat up more. ( * random numbers thrown out for example)